# Playwright retry on actions

Tags: playwright

I have a scenario here:
Click element A (a button), trigger element B (say, a div) to appear. However due to multiple factors, clicking might fail to trigger the event. The reason could be clicking too soon when he page is actually fully settled. So I need to redo the click a couple of times. There not seem to be a mechanism with in Playwright to do step level retry when condition is not met.
It sounds like a common requirement in test automation though. I am wondering how do you tackle this problem.

Some suggestion or custom code to retry failed steps?

Comment: `try`/`catch` and/or write a loop? This is awfully vague, so there's no clear code problem to solve. If you wouldn't mind sharing the actual page and your code attempt so far, it'd be much easier to provide a real solution that actually works for your use case, rather than a hand-wavey general answer that probably won't work for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`.toPass`](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#retrying)

```
await expect(async () => {
  await page.locator('button').click();
  await expect(page.locator('div')).toBeVisible();
}).toPass();
```

It'll retry the code you'll give it and wait for it to pass.

Comment: The site is down and I can't verify it right away, but it does look like what I am after! Thanks!